# The database connection error occurred while adding data to SQL in Symfony 6. ArrayCollection" given at property path "availability"

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

When I access Sonata Admin and try to add a product, I encounter the following error: "Expected argument of type '?App\Entity\Availability', 'Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection' given at property path 'availability'." What could be the issue?

Product.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Post;
use App\Dto;
use App\Dto\EmptyDto;
use App\Entity\Base\BaseModel;
use App\Entity\Trait\MainTranslationTrait;
use App\Entity\Translation\ProductTranslation;
use App\Repository\ProductRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Gedmo\Translatable\Translatable;
use mysql_xdevapi\Collection;
use phpDocumentor\Reflection\Types\Boolean;

#[ORM\Table(name: 'product')]
#[Gedmo\TranslationEntity(class: self::TRANSLATION_ENTITY)]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ProductRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Post(uriTemplate: '/view/{id}', input: EmptyDto::class),
        new Post(routeName: 'app_product_new', input: Dto\ProdDto::class),
        new Post(uriTemplate: '/edit/{id}', input: Dto\ProdDto::class),
        new Post(uriTemplate: '/delete/{id}', input: EmptyDto::class),
    ],
)]
class Product implements Translatable
{
    use MainTranslationTrait;
    use BaseModel;

    public const TRANSLATION_ENTITY = ProductTranslation::class;

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', nullable: true)]
    #[Gedmo\Translatable]
    private ?string $title = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)]
    private ?string $description = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)]
    private ?string $direction = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    private ?\DateTime $date = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', nullable: true)]
    private ?string $image = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Category::class, inversedBy: 'product')]
    private ?object $category;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Availability::class, inversedBy: 'product')]
    private \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $availability;



    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * @param string|null $title
     */
    public function setTitle(?string $title): void
    {
        $this->title = $title;
    }



    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->availability;
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * @param string|null $description
     */
    public function setDescription(?string $description): void
    {
        $this->description = $description;
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getDirection(): ?string
    {
        return $this->direction;
    }

    /**
     * @param string|null $direction
     */
    public function setDirection(?string $direction): void
    {
        $this->direction = $direction;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getAvailability(): \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
    {
        return $this->availability;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $availability
     */
    public function setAvailability(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $availability): void
    {
        $this->availability = $availability;
    }



    /**
     * @return \DateTime|null
     */
    public function getDate(): ?\DateTime
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime|null $date
     */
    public function setDate(?\DateTime $date): void
    {
        $this->date = $date;
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getImage(): ?string
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    /**
     * @param string|null $image
     */
    public function setImage(?string $image): void
    {
        $this->image = $image;
    }



    public function getCategory(): ?Category
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function setCategory(?Category $category): static
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Available.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Post;
use App\Dto;
use App\Dto\EmptyDto;
use App\Entity\Base\BaseModel;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Gedmo\Translatable\Translatable;

#[ORM\Entity]
#[ORM\Table(name: 'availability')]
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Post(uriTemplate: '/view/{id}', input: EmptyDto::class),
        new Post(routeName: 'app_post_new', input: Dto\EmptyDto::class),
        new Post(uriTemplate: '/edit/{id}', input: Dto\EmptyDto::class),
        new Post(uriTemplate: '/delete/{id}', input: EmptyDto::class),
    ],
)]
class Availability
{

    use BaseModel;

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', nullable: true)]
    private ?string $language = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Product::class, mappedBy: 'availability')]
    private mixed $product;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->product = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int|null $id
     */
    public function setId(?int $id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getLanguage(): ?string
    {
        return $this->language;
    }

    /**
     * @param string|null $language
     */
    public function setLanguage(?string $language): void
    {
        $this->language = $language;
    }



    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getProduct(): mixed
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $product
     */
    public function setProduct(mixed $product): void
    {
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    public function addProduct(Product $product): static
    {
        if (!$this->product->contains($product)) {
            $this->product->add($product);
            $product->setAvailability($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeProduct(Product $product): static
    {
        if ($this->product->removeElement($product)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($product->getAvailability() === $this) {
                $product->setAvailability(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }


}
```

Could the issue be in the constructor of the Availability class?

Comment: No, the issue is not in the constructor of the Availability class. ... If Product.availability is ManyToMany, the setter of a ManyToMany should take a `Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection` (its implementing classes are e.g. ArrayCollection and PersistentCollection (which doctrine usually uses)). Instead of a setter, you can have (both!) addAvailability and removeAvailability instead. The getter should return an Array or a Collection (and be consistent with the setter, if you have one). Finally, don't use `mixed` or `?object`, use `Collection` on the properties.

Comment: essentially, the Availability class looks great, when it comes to the product field (instead for imho the singular there), Product.availability should be the same, but it looks like a ManyToOne instead, but you define it as ManyToMany.

Comment: @Jakumi now i have another error - An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("You must define an `associated_property` option or create a `App\Entity\Availability::__toString` method to the field option availability from service admin.product is ").

Comment: @Jakumi No, I must have a ManyToMany because all products can have multiple availabilities

Comment: the new error you got is another thing entirely, there it tries to display Availabililties (for the user to choose from), but it doesn't know how to convert an Availability to a string, and suggests multiple ways to achieve this.

Comment: @Jakumi The change of EntityType to CollectionType didn't help. now i have another error mes( can i post the formfields so you could see the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254446/discussion-between-arsen-mkrtumian-and-jakumi).